# Why will HTML files load properly, while PHP files will not?

Tags: php, html

I have two simple test files, one a basic HTML document that displays a simple message and the other a PHP document that does the same.

If I access the HTML document using  a URL like this it displays properly:

```
sample.com/test.html
```

If I access the PHP file in a similar manner it also displays properly:

```
sample.com/test.php
```

Accessing the HTML file from a subdirectory also works just fine:
    sample.com/somedirectory/test.html

However, accessing the PHP page in a similar manner does not work:

```
sample.com/somedirectory/test.php
```

It produces this error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@samplehs.pltwcs.org and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`
>   **EDIT**
>   Here is the HTML code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        hello world
    </body>
</html>
```

And the PHP code:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Here's what the server's error log has to say:

```
[Wed Dec 18 12:58:08 2013] [error] [client 71.222.168.54] File does not exist: /home/username/public_html/500.shtml
[Wed Dec 18 12:58:08 2013] [error] [client 71.222.168.54] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/username/public_html/somedirectory/test.php" is writeable by group
```

Comment: What appears in the the server error log?

Comment: please post some code so that we can try to find the error

Comment: We need to see the log. Please, paste the output of the following command:
    `tail -n 100 /var/log/apache2/error.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the permissions of your PHP files to `644` and folders to `755` because your server has `suEXEC` enabled.

From the terminal you should run `chmod 644 test.php` or use any FTP client to set your permissions

[Source](http://www.itdesignlab.com/php/error-softexception-in-applicationcpp256.html)
[Source #2](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/46445/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error `File "/home/username/public_html/somedirectory/test.php" is writeable by group` your server is using something like suphp, and you need to remove write permissions from group: `chmod go-w /home/username/public_html/somedirectory/test.php` from command line.

Comment: Setting the permissions to 644, as noted by sjagr, would also work but would reset any "other permissions" you have.

Really since it's using suphp/suexec you could set them to 600, so that no one else on the web server can look at them (and should, at LEAST for anything containing "sensitive" info -- database passwords, etc.)